# Getting permissions errors related to /var/folders directory after doing mac migration

Tags: spacemacs, osx

I am running spacemacs emacs and recently had to migrate my macbook to a new macbook. After doing that, I am having trouble using magit. When I try to commmit using magit from the magit status interface, I get an error:

> files--ensure-directory: Creating directory: Permission denied, /var/folders/8sUnable to load color "#212026"

I also see what seems to be a related error on startup:

> Error running timer ‘mac-setup-help-topics’: (file-missing "Creating file with prefix" "No such file or directory" "/var/folders/8s/y0zrtc6n38j0gwnvz7_l4q1h0000gn/T/jka-com")

I've got no idea how to go about debugging for fixing this. Does anyone have any ideas?

What I've tried so far:
1) Remove the `.emacs.d` folder and reinstall spacemacs. 
2) Reinstall the emacs for mac release from [here](https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport/releases/tag/emacs-26.2-mac-7.6.1)

Comment: `/var/folders` (aka `/private/var/folders`) on macOS are for per user temporary files and caches. It sounds like, as part of your migration, you pulled over a magit "cache" that was _stored elsewhere_, and that is referring to folders in `/var/folders` that obviously no longer exist. You need to "clear" this "magit cache". Not, being a magit user I couldn't tell you where to look, but I understand its docs are pretty good. You could also try a `find/grep` from your home directory, a la `find ~/ -type f | xargs grep y0zrtc6n38j0gwnvz7`, and see what results you get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here has to do with a variable `TMPDIR` set in the `.spacemacs.env` directory. This env variable for spacemacs specifies a folder in `/var/folders`. Since that folder no longer existed when I migrated, things started to break.

The fix was to rename/delete `.spacemacs.env` and then restart emacs/spacemacs.

Comment: Thanks! Took me a minute to locate that file. For others, it's `~/.spacemacs.d/.spacemacs.env`